# WPF Stackpanel spacing between custom controls

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, spacing, stackpanel

how is it possible to get a space between some custom controls inside a stackpanel? I did it right before with a Textbox, Button, and so on, but i cannot do it with a custom control.

That's the code i've got so far

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel x:Name="spTasks" CanVerticallyScroll="True">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="local:SmartTaskOverview">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,50,50,50" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is SmartTaskOverview? I've create project, create some SmartTaskOverview (inherits ContentControl) and it's all great...

Comment: Does your SmartTaskOverview inherit from UserControl? If you have another stackpanel as the root component on the SmartTaskOverview, this could be messing up the margins.

Comment: SmartTaskOverview is the custom Control, and it inherits from UserControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FrameworkElement`s and their sub-classes don't just look for a resource using the controls type, they use the value of DefaultStyleKey. It's common practice for most sub-classes of Control (and some other `FrameworkElement`s) to override the default value of this dependency property in the static constructor to be the type of the control, but sub-classes of `UserControl` usually don't bother.

```
static Foo()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Foo), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(Foor));
}
```

If you didn't do this in your `SmartTaskOverview` then it will be looking for its default style using `typeof(UserControl)` as the resource key and not `typeof(SmartTaskOverview)`.

Note: The `UserControl` will require a control template to show its children, this is normally provided by the default style for `UserControl` but by changing the key it will find your default style instead. To resolve this, just base your style on the `UserControl` style.

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:SmartTaskOverview" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type UserControl}}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,50,50,50" />
</Style>
```

Alternatively you could provide a simple template yourself.

```xml
<Style TargetType="local:SmartTaskOverview">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="50,50,50,50" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SmartTaskOverview}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: So if i understood you right, i need to make a static method like your mentioned one inside my Custom Control class?
Well if i do so, all the controls disappear.

Comment: Yes, if you want to override the default style like you did in the question, then you will need to provide a suitable DefaultStyleKey; and the best way to do that is to override it's default value in the static constructor. I have updated my answer to cover the missing controls.

Comment: Well thanks at first, but both versions don't solve my problem.
The First solution gives me the Error **The specifies value cannot be assigned. The following type was expected: "Style"**

And the second solution simply doesn't show anything again

Comment: Sorry, missed a couple of details (happens when writing these things from memory). I updated my answer and verified it works.

Comment: Hm, i think i do something wrong, your updated version 2 now shows the controls, but both solutions don't margin the SmartTaskOverviews
[screenshot](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151201/t78rgx78.png)

Comment: Try using snoop to check the actual value, perhaps it's getting a value from another source with a higher precedence.

Comment: I never have worked with snoop, but i think i found the correct entries:
[Pic1](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4189/qvu8ec92_png.htm)
[Pic2](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4189/o2rx56yt_png.htm)
[Pic3](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4189/yn3f6oig_png.htm)
[Pic4](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4189/z8w9we3t_png.htm)
[Pic5](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4189/cr4e8hzs_png.htm)

Comment: You will want to focus on the `Margin` property on your `SmartTaskOverview`, since that's the thing you are trying set in your style.

Comment: oh sorry, here is a pic focusing the SmartTaskOverview
[Screenshot](http://fs5.directupload.net/images/151201/w6obj6ma.png)

Comment: Your last screenshot shows that Margin is set to "0,0,0,0" and the "Value Source" is "Local". This indicates that someone is setting it directly on the control, outside any template or style. Such values always take precedence over values provided by styles/templates/triggers/etc. I suggest you find where you are setting it and either remove it, or change it to the value you actually want.

Comment: Yes, ur right, directly inside SmartTaskOverview was set Margin="0". Thanks alot for your help!!